# Receiving Divide by 0 error while finding price per unit

Tags: sql

I am writing a query to take the total cost of a product and dividing by the quantity to get the price per unit and am receiving the following error

Divide by zero error encountered.

it is for this part of my sql code

```
    ,case when cast((isnull(T2.Quantity,0)-isnull(T2.QuantOut,0)) as nvarchar) = '0' then NULL 
     else cast((isnull(T2.CostTotal,0)/isnull(T2.Quantity,0)) as nvarchar) end as 'Cost Per Unit'
```

Here is the query I am using

```
    select T6.ItmsgrpNam 'Family', T0.ItemCode 'Issued Item', T0.BatchNum 'SAP Issued Lot', 
    Cast(T2.Notes as Nvarchar) 'Issued ParentLot', T0.WhsCode, '' 'OnHand', cast(T0.Quantity as 
    nvarchar) 'WIP', T0.DocDate
    ,case when cast((isnull(T2.Quantity,0)-isnull(T2.QuantOut,0)) as nvarchar) = '0' then NULL 
    else cast((isnull(T2.CostTotal,0)/isnull(T2.Quantity,0)) as nvarchar) end as 'Cost Per Unit'

    from IBT1 T0 with(nolock)
    inner join OITM T1 with(nolock) on T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
    inner join OBTN T2 with(nolock) on T0.BatchNum = T2.DistNumber and T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
    inner join OWOR T4 with(nolock) on T0.BsDocEntry = T4.DocEntry and T0.BsDocType = 202 --and 
    T4.Status = 'R'
    left join OBTN T3 with(nolock) on T0.BatchNum = Cast(T3.Notes as nvarchar)
    left join (Select 'yes' 'Value', BsDocEntry from IBT1 with(nolock) where basetype = 59 and 
    bsdoctype = 202 and Docdate <= '20191010') T5 on T0.BsDocEntry = t5.BsDocEntry
    left join OITB T6 on T1.ItmsGrpCod = T6.ItmsGrpCod
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check your data. You might have a null quantity in OBTN .

Comment: `isnull(T2.Quantity,0))` must be returning zero in the denominator.  So you need to handle that in the case statement as an OR so you can't ever get the divide by zero.  Consider: `case when cast((isnull(T2.Quantity,0)-isnull(T2.QuantOut,0)) as nvarchar) = '0'  OR T2.Quantity is null then 0...`  Also why cast a numeric to varchar? leave it numeric...

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* use `varchar()` and the related types *without* a length.  SQL Server defaults the length to different values in different contexts -- and if there is an error because the length is not long enough, it is really hard to debug.

Second, you are using the wrong function.  You want `nullif()` for the denominator.  And personally I prefer `coalesce()` instead of `isnull()` because the former is *standard* SQL (`isnull()` is sometimes preferable for performance reasons).

So:

```
 coalesce(T2.CostTotal, 0)/nullif(T2.Quantity, 0)
```